# Synthesis of 5-chloro-2-ethenyl-1,3-diiodobenzene

Tags: reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

The question is basically to figure about the steps for the following transformation.

[image]

Since ethene is a electron donating group and weakly ortho para directing so it makes electrophilic substitution difficult.hence we must add bromine water($\ce{HOBr}$) to the double bond.After this if we add $\ce{Cl2}/Fe$ we will get ortho and para positions substituted by chlorine.However I am facing difficulty changing the ortho chlorine atoms to iodine.Please suggest me a way to proceed.Thanks.

Comment: A vinyl group is electron donating and is weakly *ortho-para* directing.

Comment: @ron thanks for your comment.I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Masking your double bond  through addition of one bromine atom is a reasonable first step.  Take a look at [this earlier answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41534/synthesis-of-2-methyl-4-nitrophenol-from-benzene/41564#41564) and consider how sulfonation and the Sandmeyer reaction might prove useful in your synthesis.