# Heating p-Bromobenzenesulfonic acid in the presence of dilute HCl

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

How do I predict the outcome of this reaction?

[image]

I expected this to be an acid base reaction leading to the formation of the weak acid para-chlorobenzenesulfonic acid. However, the answer given in the worksheet was surprising $\ce{-SO3H}$ was eliminated and the product stated was $\ce{C6H5Br}$. I would like to be acquainted with the mechanism of this unusual  reaction. I couldn't find it in Clayden or Solomon Frhyle.

Comment: Electrophilic sulfonation of aromatic rings is reversible.  The firt paragraph [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31711/thermodynamic-vs-kinetic-sulphonation-of-naphthalene/31712#31712) may be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think @ron has hit the bull's eye in the comments! I would like to elaborate upon that:

[image]

Since each step in the [sulfonation of benzene](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Organic_Chemistry/Arenes/Reactivity_of_Arenes/Nitration_and_Sulfonation_of_Benzene#Mechanism_2) is an equilbirum, sulfonation is a reversible reaction. According to Le-Chatlier's principle addition of $\ce{H+}$ ions in the solution would shift the equilibrium to the left in the **last step of sulfonation where arenium is deprotonated**, hence addition of $\ce{HCl(aq)}$ accompanied with heating for kinetic requirements results in the production of 4-bromobenzenesulfonic acid in the given reaction.  This process is called **protodesulphonylation**.

Comment: Well said!  I'll add one more point, since aromatic sulfonation is reversible it can be synthetically useful. You can use the group to block and direct (see [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41534/synthesis-of-2-methyl-4-nitrophenol-from-benzene/41564#41564) for an example) and then remove the sulfonic acid group afterwards.